# Number of ways to arrange $m$ elements in a list of length $N$ with a constraint

Tags: combinatorics

If I have a set of $m\in\mathbb{N}$ elements $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m\}$. How many ways are there to create a list of length $N \in \mathbb{N}$ where there is no restriction to the number of times an element appears but $x_i$ cannot appear after $x_j$ if $i<j$?

Comment: Is this related to the number of ways to partition a set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a_{i}$ denotes the number of $x_{i}$ in the list. $\sum_{i=1}^{m}{a_{i}}=N$.

number of non negative solutions is $\binom{N+m-1}{m-1}$

put simply, we do not determine where each element located in the list, we just determine how many times they appear. because the constraint eliminate the need to consider permutation

Comment: I don’t understand where you get those numbers from. Could you help me understand please?

Comment: @Anteater23 I used stars and bars to obtain the number of non negative solutions . try to read that from wikipedia or other source

Comment: Thank you I will. One question why does the order of the $c_i$ not matter when I want it to matter i.e. ordering not satisfied means it doesn’t count as a list.

Comment: @Anteater of course order matters, what i said is, once we determine what element makes the list and how much each, then we just order the $x_{i}$s based on their subscript, from smallest to biggest. they are self ordering! :)

Comment: Ah makes sense thank you for explaining

Comment: I understand. There’s N+m-1 spaces and you have to choose m-1 spaces for the bars hence (N+m-1)C(m-1) ways!

Comment: @Anteater yes right, that is for non negative solution. for positive solution it is $\binom{n-1}{m-1}$

Comment: What do you mean by non-negtive

Comment: i mean if $a_{i}$ can be zero then there are $\binom{n+m-1}{m-1}$ solutions but if $a_{i}$ must be greater than zero there are $\binom{n-1}{m-1}$ solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^{m}{a_{i}}=n$

Comment: Ok. I allow ai=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105945/discussion-between-rezha-adrian-tanuharja-and-anteater23).